# Stop selenium to wait for all network completed

Tags: selenium

I was doing selenium test behind on dev server behind the proxy.
Since the pages has some resources (i.e ads) that blocked by the proxy, the pages are in waiting state until it got network timeout.
So, when I navigate to another page using click, the selenium is waiting for the page to be fully loaded before continue the test.

Is there any way to stop selenium waiting for the page fully loaded, since the resources blocked by the proxy isn't actually needed for the test.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This question actually brough up multiple times. Because it often does not make sense to stop loading resources since you always do not know what resource needs to be stopped from loading. In case you really want to do, it can be accomplished though a simple `javascript` hack.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return window.stop;");
```

Alrternatively,
You also can use `Actions`

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```

Depending on the language binding it may change. My example is in `java`