# How to stop page load in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

I have logged into an account on one of the websites. After login, a click on a button presents that page, but the page keeps on loading without displaying the next page.

What I wanted is, if the page keeps on loading without giving any response for some time, I need to stop the execution of the script.

I have tried by using the below code, but it didn't work

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firefox, use firefox profile with selenium and set *network.http.connection-timeout* to seconds (for ex I am setting it to 10 secs) -

In Java,

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.http.connection-timeout", 10);
```

Comment: Actually I need this to happen only in one place, not in all pages of the application. If I want to stop the execution of script only in one condition means, how I can implement

Comment: Then, try to find out the shortcut for stopping the page load and send it via sendKeys or Actions.

Comment: for using shortcuts see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202557/stop-selenium-to-wait-for-all-network-completed

Answer (score 0):

For stopping the page-load you can use this

```
public void stopPageLoading() {
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("return window.stop");
        }
```